# Separate GraphQL-AppSync-Schema-Resolver code from UI ReactJS code

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am developing ReactJs-GraphQL-aws appsync  based application. build and configuration is based on aws amplify. currently everything is in same source code. can we have separate package for UI and back-end.

for e.g. React -redux and all UI stuff will be in one code repo/package. and GraphQL-appsync resolver related code will be in separate code base or separate code repo. and if yes could you please explained more how to do that. or do you think it is a good option to keep UI and backend separate.

Please let me know if i have explained it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to have the same backend resources powering multiple front-end applications then I think it is a good idea to break it out into a different project. If you would like to do so I would recommend leaving your Amplify project as the backend directory and then moving your front end code into a new project.

Are you using Amplify codegen tools? The codegen command accepts an --api-id argument that could be used from the frontend projects now that you have them split out.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. usage of backend resources are specific to one front-end application. there is no plan for multiple front-end. in that case do you think code base spit is required. my thought is, if i split then frond-end developers can work on frontend and backend dev team for appsync resources. w.r.t your another question, i am not using amplify codegen tool.

Comment: Yeah I think it still makes sense to split it out especially if you want to have multiple teams managing it.

Comment: again in one hand thinking about full stack developer, where every one should develop their respective ui components as well as GraphQL end to end backend part. negative side is every one has to learn so many aws serverless tech stack which is good w.r.t full stack development, but it may delay project timeline as well as tough to maintain common pattern through out GraphQL schema. any thought?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning on having a single ReactJS client, then I don't think it's necessary to split the code base. The great thing about amplify, is that it will generate the queries, mutations, inputs, filters, and subscriptions based upon your annotated type schema. It'll place this in the front end `src` folder, so your front end developers only have to `import { listAllTypes } from '/src/graphql/queries.js'` and then use that query in their client code. There won't need to be separation, because your front end developers will only ever work within the `project_root/src` directory, and your backend developers will only ever work within the `project_root/amplify/backend` directory. Using a good git workflow will keep these concerns distinct between teams.